# Ensuring Async Service Initialization Is Complete?

Tags: angular

I'm using an injectable angular service to provide a Date throughout my application.
This Date value is dependant on a `http.get()` request to the server.

```
constructor(...)
{
    this.http.get(...).subscribe(r => { this.foo = r; });
}

public getFoo() : Date
{
    return Bar.dateFrom(this.foo);
}
```

Is there any way I can ensure the request is completed and `this.foo` is populated before the service is made available to the components?
I understand that I could return an `Observable<Date>` instead and `.subscribe()` everywhere, but that would make the code in many places throughout the application more complex and less readable only to cover one extreme case / race condition.

Is there any other way to ensure we wait initially for the request to come back? The rest of the application can't to anything without it anyways, so I wouldn't mind it to be synchronous here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the correct way to do this is to include the following in `app.module.ts`:

```
export function initConfig(foo: MyImportantService)
{
      return () =>
      {
        return foo.load();
      };
}

@NgModule({
...
   providers:
        [
        ...
        MyImportantService,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initConfig, deps: [MyImportantService], multi: true }
        ...
        ]
```

and have your service implement a `load` method like:

```
public load() : Promise<any>
{
  this.http.get(...)
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .toPromise()
    .then((r) => {
       this.importantVariable = r;
     });
}
```

This way the `APP_INITIALIZER` will wait for the Promise to resolve before loading the application and you can return the variable from the service directly without having to go through an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

In your http call,

```
 this.http.get(...).subscribe(
r => { this.foo = r; },
(error)=> console.log(error),
()=> // call completed. Do something);
```

In third parameter of subscribe, your http call is completed, and here you can write code for what you wish to do after call is completed.